# What's the correct way to create and show an UIBarButtonItem programmatically?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, uibarbuttonitem

I'm having a problem: the app I'm working on crashes every time an `UIBarButtonItem` is tapped.

I'm creating the button in the viewDidLoad method of my main ViewController:

```
UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showSettings)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingsButton;
```

The `showSettings` method only contains an NSLog():

```
- (void)showSettings {
    NSLog(@"ciao");
}
```

The button is correctly showed in the navigation bar, but whenever is tapped the application crashes with an `exc_bad_access` message.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: ARC is ebabled and I'm running the code in the iOS 5.1 simulator.

Comment: Nothing. The problem will be somewhere else. It works me well, i tried it!

Comment: are you trying with ARC enabled?

Comment: YES, i tried it with ARC, and i copied exactly your code. The log is 'ciao' every-time, if i push the button.

Comment: This is what I get: -[__NSCFString showSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b63280.

I bet I'm doing something incredibly stupid, those kind of errors are the most difficult to find.

Comment: It means, that your ViewConroller has no showSettings method. Are you sure, that this method is implemented exactly by the ViewController which creates the UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: YES, I'm sure. It's in the same ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Changes:

```
UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showSettings:)]; 

- (void) showSettings:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem, the app keeps crashing.

Comment: Did you put the ":" at the end of the method name at the selector setup?

Comment: You don't have to is the method you want to invoke don't take any argument.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the [ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocSelectors.html) doc about selector:

> If an object receives a message to perform a method that isn’t in its
>   repertoire, an error results. It’s the same sort of error as calling a
>   nonexistent function. But because messaging occurs at runtime, the
>   error often isn’t evident until the program executes.

So make sure your method is in the scope of your viewcontroller. I will start by checking you don't have any typo. If your method don't take any argument don't use `:` and make sure you have declared your method in your class description.

Answer (score 0):

To create a uibarbutton programatically. this example is for custom uibarbutton

```
UIButton *timebutton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 40) ];
[timebutton setTitle:timeString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[timebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  
                                      initWithCustomView:timebutton];
[rightBarButtonItem1 setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

//set the action for button
rightBarButtonItem1.action =  @selector(navigationMethod:);


self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem1;


//Method declaration
-(IBAction)navigationMethod:(id)sender{
 // action
}
```

Hope this helps you